# Unabl to make a sql query with WITH keyword to sub query

Tags: sql, select, conditional-statements, subquery, keyword

This is the original query :

```
with policy_debit(TOTAL_POLICY_DEBIT_AMOUNT) as
                (
                    select SUM(POLICY_DEBIT_AMOUNT) as TOTAL_POLICY_DEBIT_AMOUNT from
                    (select
                        CASE WHEN (ais.BILLING_TYPE_ID = 1 AND ai.STORED_INST_BALANCE <> 0 )
                             THEN ((ISNULL(STORED_INST_BALANCE,0) + ISNULL(ait.COMMISSION_AMOUNT,0)
                                + ISNULL(ait.AWARDED_COMMISSION_AMOUNT,0)))
                             WHEN (ais.BILLING_TYPE_ID = 2 AND ISNULL(ai.STORED_INST_AMOUNT,0)-ISNULL(ait.PAID_AMOUNT_IN_BODRO,0) != 0)
                             THEN  (ISNULL(ai.STORED_INST_AMOUNT,0) - ISNULL(ait.PAID_AMOUNT_IN_BODRO,0)
                                +ISNULL(ait.COMMISSION_AMOUNT,0) + ISNULL(ait.AWARDED_COMMISSION_AMOUNT,0))
                        END as POLICY_DEBIT_AMOUNT
                        from AC_INSTALLMENT ai
                        inner join AC_INSTALLMENT_TRK ait on ai.ID = ait.ID
                        inner join AC_INSTALLMENT_STATUS ais on ai.ID = ais.INSTALLMENT_ID AND ai.LAST_INSTALLMENT_STATUS_ID = ais.ID
                        inner join P_POLICY pol on ai.POLICY_ID = pol.ID
                        where
                        pol.AGENT_ACCOUNT_ID = 3039262
                        and ai.INSTALLMENT_STATUS not in (4,10005)-- Installment Status not Cancelled or Archived
                        and ((ais.BILLING_TYPE_ID = 1 AND ai.STORED_INST_BALANCE <> 0) OR
                        (ais.BILLING_TYPE_ID = 2 AND ISNULL(ai.STORED_INST_AMOUNT,0)-ISNULL(ait.PAID_AMOUNT_IN_BODRO,0) != 0))
                        
                          and convert(Date,ais.INTERMEDIARY_DUE_DATE) <= convert(DATE,getdate())
                        and ai.ID not in
                        (   select ai2.ID from
                            AC_INSTALLMENT ai2 left join AC_CHEQUE_INST_MATCHING cim on ai2.ID = cim.INSTALLMENT_ID
                            left join AC_CHEQUE_MATCHING cm on cm.ID = cim.CHEQUE_MATCHING_DETAILS_ID
                            left join AC_CHEQUE ac on ac.ID = cm.CHEQUE_ID
                            left join P_POLICY pol on pol.ID = ai2.POLICY_ID
                            where pol.AGENT_ACCOUNT_ID = 3039262
                            and(
                                ((ai2.COLLECTION_METHOD_ID=1000001 and convert(Date,ais.INTERMEDIARY_DUE_DATE) >= convert(DATE,getdate()))
                                or( ai2.COLLECTION_METHOD_ID=1 and ac.CHEQUE_STATUS_ID  in (10001,1000001)
                                    and (convert(Date,ac.MATURITY_DATE) >= convert(DATE,getdate()) and cm.ACCOUNT_ID=3039262 ))
                                )
                            )
                        )  
                    ) as temp
                ),

                  --To calculate UNALLOCATED_INTERMEDIARY_COMMISSION, we are first considering the installments which has been paid, (In this case
                        -- the AC_ENTRY.INSTALLMENT_ID will not be null) and for which the intermediaryDueDate has come
                        --And then we are considering the installments which has not been paid yet. (in this case, AC_ENTRY.INSTALLMENT_ID is null)
                        unallocated_commission(UNALLOCATED_INTERMEDIARY_COMMISSION)  as (
                        select sum(ISNULL(ENTRY_BALANCE,0)) as UNALLOCATED_INTERMEDIARY_COMMISSION from (
                        select aeb.ENTRY_BALANCE from AC_ENTRY ae
                        inner join AC_ENTRY_BALANCE aeb on ae.ID = aeb.ENTRY_ID
                        left join AC_INSTALLMENT ai on ai.ID = ae.INSTALLMENT_ID
                        left join AC_INSTALLMENT_STATUS ais on ai.ID = ais.INSTALLMENT_ID AND ai.LAST_INSTALLMENT_STATUS_ID = ais.ID
                        where ae.ACCOUNT_ID = 3039262       -- Intermediary Account Id
                        and ae.SUPER_ENTRY_TYPE = 5     -- Intermediary Comission
                        and ae.ENTRY_STATUS in (2,4)    -- Payable or Partially Paid
                        and aeb.ENTRY_BALANCE != 0
                        and REFERENCE_ID is null
                        and (ae.INSTALLMENT_ID is null or ae.INSTALLMENT_ID in (
                                select ai.ID from AC_INSTALLMENT ai JOIN AC_INSTALLMENT_STATUS ais on ai.ID = ais.INSTALLMENT_ID
                                AND ai.LAST_INSTALLMENT_STATUS_ID = ais.ID
                                AND convert(DATE,ais.INTERMEDIARY_DUE_DATE) <= convert(DATE,getdate())
                                ))
                            ) as temp2
                        ),  

                unpaid_commission(UNPAID_COMMISSION_IN_BORDRO) as (
                    select SUM(ISNULL(AMOUNT,0)) as UNPAID_COMMISSION_IN_BORDRO
                    from AC_ENTRY ae
                    left join AC_INSTALLMENT ai on ae.INSTALLMENT_ID = ai.id
                    where ae.ACCOUNT_ID = 3039262   -- Intermediary Account Id
                    and ae.SUPER_ENTRY_TYPE = 5 -- Intermediary Comission
                    and ae.ENTRY_STATUS = 2     -- Payable
                    and ae.REFERENCE_ID is not null
                    and not exists (select * from AC_INSTALLMENT_HISTORY his
                                                JOIN AC_INSTALLMENT_STATUS status ON his.id=status.INSTALLMENT_HISTORY_ID
                                                where status.INSTALLMENT_STATUS = 3
                                                and his.INSTALLMENT_ID = ae.REFERENCE_ID)
                    and (ae.INSTALLMENT_ID is null or ae.INSTALLMENT_ID in (
                                select ai.ID from AC_INSTALLMENT ai JOIN AC_INSTALLMENT_STATUS ais on ai.ID = ais.INSTALLMENT_ID
                                AND ai.LAST_INSTALLMENT_STATUS_ID = ais.ID
                                AND convert(DATE,ais.INTERMEDIARY_DUE_DATE) <= convert(DATE,getdate())
                         ))
                )
                SELECT ((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(TOTAL_POLICY_DEBIT_AMOUNT),0) FROM policy_debit) +
                (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(UNPAID_COMMISSION_IN_BORDRO),0) FROM unpaid_commission) +
                (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(UNALLOCATED_INTERMEDIARY_COMMISSION),0) FROM unallocated_commission)) as TOTAL_AGENT_DEBT_OR_OPEN_BAL_OR_DUE_DEBT
```

I just need to add select * from ( above query). But it is giving me error like
SQL Error [156] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. Please help me out how can I make the above query to sub query.

Comment: Did you write all that code without trying it once during the process?!? Take smaller steps.

Comment: Need to add a semi-colon before the WITH. Most devs prefer to put the semi-colon at the end of the previous query, but I prefer put it as a prefix ```;WITH policy_debit...``` in case the query above changes. Kind of ugly to look at, but more forgiving when the code changes